# If mouse reaches far left of screen perform an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi im looking for a way so that if my mouse moves to the far left or right of the screen an action will be performed is there a way to do this with html css jquery etc? Like im trying to get my navbar to show when my mouse is reaches the left end of the screen. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're better off showing you've attempted to do this yourself, rather than just asking how to do it in the first place.

Comment: For your future reference, you may also think in terms of viewport, or window, instead of the general screen. (not that window is any better anyway). :)

Comment: I would set up a transparent overlay `<div>` on the left side of `<body>` and then bind to the hover event. Also note that mobile devices wouldn't have access to the navbar if you rely on this kind of events

Answer (score 4):

See here http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Based on the examples, you can then use pageX and pageY to determine position of the mouse. You could probably have something like this:

```
$("body").on("mousemove",function(event) {
    if (event.pageX < 50) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd say that assuming 50 px as narrow is quite bold

Comment: @JanDvorak You're probably right, but I'm hoping the poster can figure out to change that value to whatever is appropriate to their needs.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make it overly complicated. Just position your menu as a transparent layer, key hover to expand and show the menu links.

```
#menu { overflow: hidden; 
background-color: transparent; 
width: 20px; 
height: 100%;    
position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
#menu:hover { width: auto; background-color: red; height: 100% }
.link { margin-left: 20px; display: block; }

<div id="menu">
<a class="link" href="#">LINK</a>
<a class="link" href="#">LINK</a>
<a class="link" href="#">LINK</a>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle showing how it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/6cgZZ/
If you want to lock the menu in place, then you will probably want to use JS to trigger a mouseover event, but I would still use a transparent element to use as a trigger. In that case, using DOM you can dynamicly alter the menu's properties, like visibility, width, etc.